# Add bezier curves when moving points on segmented cube in Cinema 4D Lite

Tags: cinema4d

I have a cube in Cinema 4D Lite that I segmented so I could move the middle of one face of the cube up higher. How can I make that curved with bezier so the top of the cube is curved, rather than pointed? Here is a screenshot of what I have so far:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cannot write comments without reputation, but here's one written as an answer:

Obviously you should learn the following basic methods:

- extrusion
- the Sweep tool
- the Lathe tool
- Boolean operations

You'll find easily numerous tutorials.

Make it simple, have the right curved form in the beginning. Extrude a rectangle which has one side curved. Add the edge roundings afterwards. The results of all three phases are shown in the next image:

[image]

The other methods are not needed for this, but maybe you need them later today, when you want something more complex. For example with booleans you can subtract a curved piece from the top of the cube.

In theory it's possible that you already know this all and now you expect a way how to bend one planar face to the right predefined curvature. It's tricky and I'm not at all sure if any exact tool to do it is available in C4D. I know only how to do it by having the right curve in the beginning or by subtracting. Subdivision, pulling some faces and rendering as smoothed is the sculptor's way, but it's not exact, it's sculpting.